# Flash text box formatting differences

Tags: flash

I have two text boxes on the same window. They are both set to Arial 14 Regular but they both appear very differently.

To see what I am referring to: http://www.bendelcorp.com/toolscalculators.html and go to the Conversion Tools at the bottom of the page. Click on Surface Finish and type in a value in the two different fields and click calculate. I really don't see anything that could be causing this difference in appearance.

Any guidance for troubleshooting this will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've resized the textfields differently. You probably resized the right field with percentages in 'Transform' box. And the left field with pixel width in the 'Info' or 'Properties' box.

If you want the font to remain unscaled, but want to resize the textfield use the pixel width and height properties, not the percentage width and height of the textfield.

As a matter of fact: I think you resized them both with the 'Transform' option. They both look unnatural.

So in conclusion: set the percentages in the Transform options to 100% width and 100% height. And resize the fields in pixels in the 'Info' or 'Properties' boxes, or use the resize handles of the textfields.

Comment: spot on. Whoever built this probably did it using Transform. I rebuilt the fields, copied and pasted to retain uniformity and everything is looking good. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks like you have a scaling problem. Did you add the textfields via code or did you use the Flash Authoring Tool?

Did you maybe scale one of the two textboxes?

PS: If you added them via ActionScript could you maybe post the code?